# escape quotations in JSON when printing values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Ok so it's really late on a friday and im awful at json/js.

I have an array like this:

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "metadata": "BandwidthA,HourlyA,MonthlyA"
}
```

I'm spitting it out into elements by `id` 1 through 3 like so:

```
var a = JSON.stringify(row.metadata);
var b = a.split(',');
$("#resulta1").text(a1);
$("#resulta2").text(a2);
$("#resulta3").text(a3);
```

but in the html i'm getting the leading `"` and the ending `"`

Is there an easy way to escape this? So i only get:

- BandwidthA
- HourlyA
- MonthlyA

and not...

- "BandwidthA
- HourlyA
- MonthlyA"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you stringifying?

Comment: Just a note: That's not an array, that's an object.  It's known as an associative array in many other languages, but in Javascript/JSON, we only have regular arrays, as well as objects.

Comment: Thanks @Chrissi - i'm new to using js/json like this so wasn't too sure :-)

Answer (score 2):

Don't stringify `row.metadata` - it's already a string! (the value of the `metadata` property that is, `row` is the object it resides in) `stringify` is used to turn an object into a stringified version of that object, typically to be parsed by a backend.

```
var = row.metadata;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use JSON.stringify on the String, if you don't want to have the Quotes as part of your result, because that's where it comes from, just use:

```
var a = row.metadata;
var b = a.split(',');
$("#resulta1").text(b[1]);
$("#resulta2").text(b[2]);
$("#resulta3").text(b[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not need to stringify and then split. You can directly split `row.metadata` by `,` and then use those values.

Try this.

```
var a = row.metadata.split(',');
$("#resulta1").text(a[1]);
$("#resulta2").text(a[2]);
$("#resulta3").text(a[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering if you even need to use JSON.stringify since metadata is already a string. JSON.stringify will add quotes to your string so you will end up with double quotes!